# Cannot start dask client

Tags: python, numpy, dask, dask-distributed

When I try and initiate a dask distributed cluster with:

```
from dask.distributed import Client, progress
client = Client(threads_per_worker=1, n_workers=2)
client
```

I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: Cluster failed to start: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool8'`

I have `numpy==1.22.4` installed which is required by another library (it requires `< 1.23`). I have `dask==2023.1.0` installed.

Will it work with an older version of `dask`? If so which one should I use?

Comment: I installed using `pip install dask` (without Array support) and that seems to work. I do not need the Array support for my use case but it would be good to get this resolved.

Comment: You title mentions "dash"?

Comment: Thank you for the catch, type ahed :)

Comment: Dask is currently tested agains numpy 1.18 https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/main/continuous_integration/environment-mindeps-array.yaml#L15 . Maybe you have something else called "numpy" in your path?